# Clarification about Replace and Dtypes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a strange problem. I don't have the possibility to produce a MVE.

I have two dataset in pandas. They contain **some Series** that can have three values: "Yes", "No", NaN. These Series have Dtype Object at this moment.

I want to remove the NaNs from them, and to prepare them to be used by ML algorithms, so I do this:

```
final_df1 = d1.dropna(how='any').replace({"Yes":1, "No":0})
final_df2 = d2.dropna(how='any').replace({"Yes":1, "No":0})
```

In `final_df1` the Dtype of the Series I mentioned before becomes automatically `int64` after dropping the NaN values and replacing the values. In `final_df2`, this does not happen. They contain the same values (0 and 1) so I really do not understand this.

In order to create a Minimum Viable Example, I tried to

- Isolate the Series, do the transformation on them one by one and check the results
- Take only a small portion of the Dataframes
- Save the DFs on disk and work on them from another script to recreate the problem

But, in any of those attempts, the result was different. Either both DFs ended up with Series having Object Dtype, or both with Int64 Dtype.

For me, this is important, because later on I need the dummies of those DFs, and if some Int series are Object series on the other DF, the columns will not match. This problem is easy to solve, I just need to cast explicitly, but still I have one doubt and I would need to confirm it:

**If I replace the content of an Object Series (without NaNs) with numbers, is there a random possibility of this Series being cast to Int64?**

I see this as the only explanation for what I am facing

Thanks in advance. If you find any way to clarify my question, please edit or comment

---

EDIT 1: Screenshots from Spyder
[image]

This is the code. I am printing in console the most essential relevant data: Dtype, values and number of Nulls

[image]

This is the output before the Drop/Replace. Well, I could have printed something more nice to read, but the idea is simple: before the Drop/Replace they both have null values, they both have "Yes" and "No" values, they both are object type Series.

[image]
Aaaaand this is after the Drop/Replace. As you can see, they both have no nulls now, they both have 1/0, but one of them is an object Series, the other is an int64 Series.

I really do not understand: they were the same type before!

Comment: Could you provide the data to reproduce?

Comment: Can you call `value_counts` on those series before and after replace? Is it possible they contain some strings after the replace (for example the string '1')?

Comment: suspecting the same thing.

Comment: @juske I cannot provide them fully, as they are industrial data. I tried to extract the single Series, or a portion of the dataset, but the problem described in the question occurred

Comment: @ayhan I checked the value_counts() before asking, and no, there are only 1 and 0 values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample to reproduce.
If you change col_1 '0' to 0 it will change the dtype

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col_1': ['Yes', 'No', np.nan, '0'], 'col_2': [np.nan, 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
d1=df[['col_1']]
d2=df[['col_2']]

print(d1.dtypes)
print(d2.dtypes)

final_df1 = d1.dropna(how='any').replace({"Yes":1, "No":0})
final_df2 = d2.dropna(how='any').replace({"Yes":1, "No":0})

print(final_df1.dtypes)
print(final_df2.dtypes)
```

you can also convert the datatypes in the final_df definition

```
final_df1 = d1.dropna(how='any').replace({"Yes":1, "No":0}).astype(int)
final_df2 = d2.dropna(how='any').replace({"Yes":1, "No":0}).astype(int)
```

Comment: As I said in the question, the problem is not reproducible. Just by copying the Series (with pd.copy()) the output change. For this reason, the question itself is "How does pandas handle this implicit casting? Is there a sense to it?"